# How to set redirection using regex in wordpress?

Tags: regex, wordpress, nsregularexpression

I would like to set redirection like

```
https://test.com/tag/1/t3 (source url) → https://test.com/tag/1/text/3 (target url)

https://test.com/tag/2/t4 (source url) → https://test.com/tag/2/text/4 (target url)
```

My current setting is

```
https://test.com/tag/([0-9]{1,})/t?([0-9]{1,}) (source url)

↓

https://test.com/tag/([0-9]{1,})/text/([0-9]{1,}) (target url)
```

This doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually tested it but a piece of code that I believe might solve the problem is as follows.

```php
// eg. $url is your URL

$regex = '/\/tag\/([0-9]{1,})\/t([0-9]{1,})/g';
$replace = '/tag/$1/text/$2';

$url = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $url);

wp_redirect($url);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about '$'. It worked!